# Powershell slow starting on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, performance, powershell

I have problem with slow starting of powershell prompt on Windows 10 ( Version 1703 - Creators Update ).

My hw specs ( quite fast machine ): Intel i5-7440HQ (Quad Core) / 32GB DDR4 RAM / 512 Samsung SSD hard drive.

I tried to bypass profile and execution policy but it does not change anything:

> powershell -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ( Measure-Command { powershell "Write-Host 1" } ).TotalSeconds
>
> **6,228067**

My friends same laptop with Windows 10 without Creators Update runs powershell in less than 0,5 sec.

Also tried do some compilation with ngen.exe but it didn't help:

```
$env:path = [Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % {
  if (! $_.location) {continue}
  $Name = Split-Path $_.location -leaf
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "NGENing : $Name"
  ngen install $_.location | % {"`t$_"}
}
```

Any idea how may I investigate this issue?

Greetings

Comment: You should start by checking your profile script to see if anything is running in there that is delaying startup. My output is 1.2774795 seconds. Also, what machine, processor, memory, other things running?

Comment: powershell is always slow to start. [But Ms ignores those complains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/01/04/rumors-of-cmds-death-have-been-greatly-exaggerated/) and only response "powershell is fast"

Comment: As You see -noprofile option is set. No difference.

Comment: I see it. send this to MS, but they ignore any reports that powershell is slow

Comment: Yea, but explain me how same laptop ( both ordered same specs ) starts powershell in less than 0,5 s and mine over 6 s? Difference is for sure that my is with Creators Update and the second one is without this update. I tried to use also Process Monitor looking for powershell.exe process, but nothing happen for 6 s and then all is in log.

Comment: again, for me powershell is also always slow. ask this Microsoft.

Comment: `70.2869261` seconds for me... if that makes you feel any better

Comment: Now I have 0,2915139 seconds. Windows 10 (1809) and that is ok! Solved after reinstall.

Answer (score 12):

This was happening to me also - though maybe not the best route, adding `powershell.exe` to the list of [Windows Defender exclusions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security) sped it up from 20 seconds to < 1 second.

Using legacy console, purging PSReadLine, and running ngen did not seem to help at all.

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick. I had an issue similar to yours where the window would open up but the path wouldn't load for more than 30 seconds. As soon as I excluded it from Defender, it loaded in a snap. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like what  I need. Did you add the exclusion as a file exclusion?

Comment: Kaspersky slowed it down for 8-10 Seconds on our systems.

Answer (score 6):

I had been experiencing the same issue for quite some time until PowerShell started failing on startup with the following error:

```
Exception:
System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllLines(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.<ReadHistoryFile>b__67_0()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.WithHistoryFileMutexDo(Int32 timeout, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.DelayedOneTimeInitialize()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Initialize(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This led me to the existing Github issue: https://github.com/Powershell/PSReadLine/issues/673

I tried deleting history file in `~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\` which was over 6 GB by then and after that PowerShell console started opening pretty quickly.

Maybe the slowness you experience is the PowerShell trying to read a big history file (which is not yet big enough to cause `OutOfMemory`).

Answer (score 4):

There can be other reasons for what causes slow Powershell start, but something that *always* causes slowdown for me is Windows update.

Instead of running `ngen` on every assembly powershell happens to have loaded, what I want to do is run `ngen update` which optimises every globally installed assembly:

```
. (Join-Path ([Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()) ngen.exe) update
```

After updating to May 2019 Win10, I see that improved the performance of

```
(measure-command { powershell.exe -command "1+1" }).TotalSeconds
```

from ~1.35s to ~0.55s.

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is to create a shortcut to `powershell.exe`, right-click on it > properties, go to tab options, click on "use legacy console". My screenreader (magic and zoomtext) couldn't stand the 'new' console which came with the fall update (Powershell was veeeerrrrry slow) With legacy on everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

After analize powershell.exe with procmon (sysinternals tool) I could see that the process was trying to do something in catroot2 folder, so after rename it (you have to stop the CryptSvc service that blocks the folder), it was created automatically. So the conclusion is that folder got corrupted. (Sorry for my bad English)

Execute the next .bat

```bash
net stop CryptSvc /y
rename c:\windows\system32\catroot2 Catroot2.bak
net start CryptSvc
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @Toto What are you talking about? I thought wolfy explained it nicely (despite his/her bad English). The catroot2 folder turned out to be corrupted, so it needed to be renamed to allow a new one to be created; but to do that, you have to first stop the CryptSvc service to unlock the folder, then start it again after renaming the folder. That's pretty much exactly what the code does. (I might add that you may, then, want to delete the old (renamed) folder if you have no further use for it.)

Comment: @RobH: I've wroten my comment before the answer was edited, the first version contained only code.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution when I googled having the same problem, but in 2022. Unfortunately this did not fix my issue.

Our systems have a group policy security requirement to "Turn on PowerShell Transcription". The policy requires that we specify "the Transcript output directory to point to a Central Log Server or another secure location". The server name changed and no one updated the policy. As soon as I updated the GPO with the new location, PowerShell opened instantly again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).