# How to make Windows Defender trust certain powershell scripts, so they don't have to be scanned when run?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-defender, file-shortcut

I read in this question that `powershell.exe` needs [to be added to the list of Windows Defender exclusions](https://superuser.com/questions/1212442/powershell-slow-starting-on-windows-10) to run faster.  That seems a little coarse-grained.

Is there a way to make sure that only certain scripts are [skipped](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security) being checked by Windows Defender, and not anything that is run from powershell.exe?

Are (self?)signed scripts skipped by Windows Defender?  Can I add my own scripts to a trusted list of scripts, so Windows Defender doesn't slow those down?

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds bad; really I just want my `.lnk`s to run faster when I press a shortcut key in Windows to run them...there seems to be this massive delay after I press the shortcut keys.

Comment: You can exclude directories.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Ramhound You mean directories of scripts?  And then it will skip checking those?  Thus making them run faster?

Comment: Yes;  You can add exclusion folders;  if it will be faster entirely depends on if it’s actually Windows Defender causing the slow down.

Comment: @Ramhound But Windows Defender is excluding powershell.exe in the question, does that mean the script still gets scanned?

Comment: Just adding an alternative approach. You could try loading a script that remains open, always listening for your keyboard shortcuts. My assumption is that Windows Defender only scans the script when it is launched. Depending on your situation, maybe you eat this scan period when the script is initially launched and then not experience the delay again since scripts have already been scanned.