# Windows powershell drastic slowdown after upgrade to v1903 from v1803

Tags: performance, powershell, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1903

I recently upgraded my PC running Windows 10 v1803 to v1903.

Windows powershell was perfectly fine to work with(in 1803). Immediately after update, powershell drastically slowed down to a great extent, which is very annoying.

Any possible reasons or methods to solve?

PC specs:
6GB ram
Nvidia GeForce210
2GB Video Card Memory
Intel corei3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell slow starting on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1212442/powershell-slow-starting-on-windows-10).  The only reason I selected this particular candiated out of the many that exist, is due to the fact you upgrade from Windows 10 version 1803 to Windows 10 version 1903 which would have included a substanial upgrade to .NET 4.8 from .NET 4.7.2[.](https://superuser.com/questions/578065/powershell-very-slow-to-open-respond)

Comment: Please include an example workload or script that is taking longer. Some starting points would be to compare your powershell and .net versions with what you had prior to the update.

Comment: I assume we are talking PowerShell 5.1 instead of PowerShell Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell very slow to open/respond](https://superuser.com/questions/578065/powershell-very-slow-to-open-respond)