# Powershell is extremely slow and using a lot of resources, how to solve this?

Tags: powershell, cmder, scoop

Using powershell is almost impossible. It takes almost 6 minutes to load on a pretty fast computer.

[image]
I think it might be relevant that I use cmder and scoop. It's also slow in cmder.

What can I do to solve it or at least find the cause?

It's a company pc and uses Sentinel One as antivirus, which I cannot modify.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1212442/powershell-slow-starting-on-windows-10?rq=1) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/578065/powershell-very-slow-to-open-respond?rq=1) answer your question? Have you tried installing PowerShell 7 to see if there is any difference?

Comment: @Ramhound sadly no, however I added some details in my question about antivirus

Comment: You should check what’s in the Powershell startup files. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/578147/219095) could be of help.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @DanielB good advice, hower none of these files exist

Comment: @harrymc Let me give it a try

Comment: If all suggestions fail, with some skill, you can use the sysinternals process monitor to see what it is actually doing under the hood.  The tool is frustrating to master but can tell you things that nothing else can.

Comment: Your PowerShell performance issues are most certainly caused by the configuration of your security software.  If you cannot change the configuration then report the issue to somebody who can.

Comment: @ramhound only peculiar thing is my colleagues don't seem to suffer the same fate. Although they use the same software mostly.

Comment: @Thomas - So what are the differences? PowerShell has to be using a profile file, so which profile, are you using?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @ramhound virtually none, I just use scoop a lot more for apps.

Comment: If your computer is domain joined, ask a collegue to log into your computer and let them start Powershell. This will determine if the problem is somewhere in your user profile or settings, or something local to your computer. Alternatively, if you are not domain joined, create a 2nd user, login with it and test there.

Comment: @Thomas - Unless you are launching PowerShell without a profile, it has to be using a profile, so which profile is it using?  It sounds like this issue requires an Administrator on your network since you don't have the information required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging some time with our sysadmin we found out that the presence of `%USERPROFILE%\scoop\apps` in the `psmodulepath` Environment Variable for the user was the culprit.